# Micronaut test on gitlab cicd pipeline data persist between differen test

Tags: testing, gitlab-ci, micronaut

I've created a pipeline in gitlab for testing my micronaut application.

Some test need a database so iI have included postgres service in the pipeline.

If I run the test locally it is working correctly but when I run it in the pipeline I can see that, just for some tests, the changes in the database are not removed at the end of the test.

For example, I have two tests classes: "Test1" and "Test2" and I execute "Test2" after "Test1".

If I create a product inside "Test1" then I can see this product in "Test2".

This only happens if the "Test1" use "EmbeddedServer" and "HttpClient".

This is an example of "Text1":

```
@Slf4j
@MicronautTest(transactional = false)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class Text1 {
    @Inject
    public EmbeddedServer server;

    @Inject
    @Client("/")
    public HttpClient client;

    @Inject
    ProductService productService;

    @Test
    void checkSomething() {
       client.toBlocking().retrieve(
                HttpRequest.POST(URL_CREATE_PRODUCT, updatePayload),
                List.class
        );
       assertEquals(1,productService.findAll().size());

    }

}
```

And this is an example of "Test2"

```
@Slf4j
@MicronautTest(transactional = false)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class Text2 {
    @Inject
    public EmbeddedServer server;

    @Inject
    @Client("/")
    public HttpClient client;

    @Inject
    ProductService productService;

    @Test
    void checkSomething() {
       productService.create(new Product());
       
       **// HERE THE ERROR IS!! FINDALL RETURNS 2**
       assertEquals(1,productService.findAll().size()); 

    }

}
```

And this is the stage from gitlab cicd:

```
test:
  tags:
    - fine-common
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: krisgeus/docker-kafka
      alias: kafka
    - name: postgres:14
  variables:
    POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    POSTGRES_USER: test
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 
    POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
    ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,INTERNAL://localhost:29092'
    LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092,INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:29092'
    SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: 'PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT'
    INTER_BROKER: 'INTERNAL'
    DB_URL_TEST: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
    DB_DIALECT: org.postgresql.Driver
    KAFKA_START_TESTCONTAINER: DISABLE
  script:
    - mvn clean test
```

Comment: Can you add the GitLab build output to the question? I guess on GitLab your Postgres is not starting or you did not map the Postgres port onto the build machine, so Micronaut cannot connect to the DB

Comment: Hi, I'm sure that that is not the problem. We have lot of test where database is working correctly and we can save/update/delete data in test. The problem is in the process to clean up the data after the test class was finished if we are using inside the test "EmbeddedServer " and "HttpClient"

Comment: Are you using Micronaut Test Resources locally? Can you post your datasource section of your application.yml? 

From the docs: "When using @MicronautTest, each @Test method will be wrapped in a transaction that will be rolled back when the test finishes. This behavior can be changed by using the transactional and rollback properties.To avoid creating a transaction: `@MicronautTest(transactional = false)`"